# For non-resident aliens, are US oil royalties classed as effectively connected income?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, non-resident, income

I am a non-resident alien; I am retired and do not conduct any business within the US.  However, I receive royalty income from some oil wells located in Oklahoma.  Is this royalty income determined to be effectively connected income and therefore should I report in on Schedule E and also Line 18 on the 1040NR and do I have to go through the fairly-lengthy election statement to have it classified as ECI?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is ECI since the income is sourced to the US. It should be reported on your 1040NR Schedule E.